# Link accessed thru selenium works in Chrome but not in IE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have encountered an issue for UI elements on IE browser. The link doesn’t respond to Selenium click commands. The same commands works fine on chrome browser.

I have used Actions also, but same problem it's not identifying the element.

**code:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '#cwt_services')]"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.moveToElement(element).perform();

WebElement subElement = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"yui-gen4\"]/a");

action.moveToElement(subElement);

action.click();

action.perform();
```

**Image** of the code:

[image]

Please help me how to handle this scenarios on IE browser.

Comment: Use JavaScript Executor to click on the element in IE browser.

Comment: What is the reason for moving to `element` and then without any interaction on it moving to `subElement`? Are you sure your code logic implements the expected user behavior?

Comment: In your code you're referring to `yui-gen4`, while your list element has id `yui-gen1`. I suppose the displayed HTML fragment is not complete, else it wouldn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a 5 second pause (for investigation purpose ONLY - remove after investigation) does it help at all with the issue?
If so u have a timing issue and will probably want a polling (explicit) wait on the element

Comment: +1 with only this context, it is probably a timing issue as IE is significantly slower compared to Chrome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find that element by using two more methods if this is not working. 
Try using CSS selectors or using a tag name `a`, because XPath doesn't work always.

Also, I assume that you have put these lines in your code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", 
                   "pathofchromedriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
```